# Angularfire take and map

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I have a little angular application (Angular 6) with angularfire2, now i want to select only one object, odered by date, i can get .take(1) or .map() but not together, how is that done?

I tried it with the following approche

```js
    return this.db.list(this.BASE_PATH, ref => ref.orderByChild(this.PUBLISH_DATE).limitToLast(1)).snapshotChanges().pipe(take(1)).pipe(map(res => {
      return res.map(item => {
        console.log(item);
      });
    }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`take(n)` only takes the first n emissions of the observable, not n items of the array emitted, see [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/take.html) for more information on the `take` operator.

You can just use `map` to sort/filter your array and return the desired value and then subscribe. Do something like this:

```
this.db.list(this.BASE_PATH, ref => ref.orderByChild(this.PUBLISH_DATE).limitToLast(1)).snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(map(arr => arr.sort((a, b) => b.date - a.date)[0]))
      .subscribe(item => {
        console.log(item);
      });
```

**EDIT:**
[This](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-h3axyc?file=src/app/app.component.ts) stackblitz might do a better job of showcasing it.